# Insertar pedidos y sus detalles en Delphi

Tags: delphi

yo de vuelta con mi formulario de pedido.
En mi formulario de pedido tengo un boton de nuevo pedido:

```
procedure TPEDIDO.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  intUltimo: integer;
begin
 
 DataModule1.qipedido.Close;
 DataModule1.qipedido.ExecSQL();
 DataModule1.qupedido.Close;
 DataModule1.qupedido.ExecSQL();
 DataModule1.qupedido.Open;
 DBEdit1.Text := inttostr(DataModule1.qupedido.FieldByName('maximop').AsInteger);


 while not DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.eof do
  begin
   DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Delete;
  end;
 DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Open;

 end;
```

donde qipedido inserta el pedido:

```
  insert into pedidos (IdPedido) values (null);
```

un solo pedido vacio.

Y qupedido me devuelve el ultimo id insertado, pero el problema es que me devuelve cero (0):

```
  select last_insert_id() as maximop from pedidos;
```

Entonces luego falla la insercion de un detalle de pedido, que si la realizo con los pedidos yua existentes funciona a la perfeccion.

Es decir cuando inserto un registro de detalle aparece un renglon en la grilla, pero cuando quiero insertar otro me dice: Must apply updates before refreshing data. Pero si estoy llamando a ApplyUpdates:

```
  procedure TPEDIDO.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);

 begin

  DataModule1.sqlquery1.Close;
 DataModule1.sqlquery1.ExecSQL();
 DataModule1.sqlquery1.Open;

 DataModule1.qidetpedido.Close;
 DataModule1.qidetpedido.ParamByName('iddp').AsInteger :=
  DataModule1.sqlquery1.FieldByName('maximo').AsInteger;
 DataModule1.qidetpedido.ParamByName('idped').AsInteger :=
  StrToInt(DBEdit1.Text);

  DataModule1.qidetpedido.ExecSQL();

 DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.ApplyUpdates(0);
 DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Refresh;
end;
```

Y lo mismo sucede con el boton de eliminar, que borra un registro:

```
 procedure TPEDIDO.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DataModule1.qedetpedido.Close;
  DataModule1.qedetpedido.ParamByName('iddp').AsInteger :=
  DataModule1.cdsdetpedidoIddp.AsInteger;

 DataModule1.qedetpedido.ExecSQL();

 DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.ApplyUpdates(0);
 DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Refresh;

end;
```

¿Cual seria la manera correcta?

Comment: ¿Realmente el INSERT del pedido a NULL te está insertando algo? Es posible que no esté insertando nada (por algun error de Base de Datos) y por eso te devuelve un 0.

Comment: Si me inserta perfectamente.. Con el id siguiente y todo. De hecho voy viendo la base de datos cuando pruebo la aplicacion.

Comment: Que pasaria si hago un Insert en el clientdataset de pedidos?

Comment: @Caruso, hay muchos errores en tu código, realmente se hace muy difícil escribir una respuesta en el formato de StackOverflow. Me temo que no has leído nada de la documentación o algún libro sobre el funcionamiento de los DataSets (en general) y de ClientDataSets en particular en Delphi. Me gustaría ayudarte, pero habría que partir esta pregunta en 5 o 10, para hacerla viable para el sitio.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices jachguate.. Voy a republicar mis dudas por separado. Perdona mi ignorancia

Comment: Nada que no se pueda resolver. Mira si [este artículo del uso de ClientDataSet](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30330) te puede ayudar un poco. Un saludo.